# Tensorboard Embedding Projector - how to show images without transparency?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, tensorboard, embedding

I was trying to visualize image feature vectors through tensorboard embedding projector.
The way I did it is to create a sprite image("sprite_all_img.jpg") and run the tensorboard using the following codes:

```html
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver([features])

    sess.run(features.initializer)
    saver.save(sess, os.path.join('C:/for_tensorboard/all_images.ckpt'))

    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
    # One can add multiple embeddings.
    embedding = config.embeddings.add()
    embedding.tensor_name = features.name
    # Link this tensor to its metadata file (e.g. labels).
    embedding.metadata_path = os.path.join('C:/for_tensorboard/metadata_16dim.tsv')
    # Comment out if you don't want sprites
    embedding.sprite.image_path = os.path.join('C:/for_tensorboard/sprite_all_img.jpg')
    embedding.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([img_data.shape[1], img_data.shape[1]])
    # Saves a config file that TensorBoard will read during startup.
    projector.visualize_embeddings(tf.summary.FileWriter('C:/for_tensorboard'), config)
```

In the Embedding Projector, I expect the images to be opaque, and only the front images can be seen when they are overlapping each other, just like what others did: [other people's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H12W0.png)
(from: https://medium.com/@kumon/visualizing-image-feature-vectors-through-tensorboard-b850ce1be7f1)

However, when I showed my images in Embedding Projector, they became somewhat transparent, and when they overlapped, the whole cluster got very 'dark' (due to many translucent images stacking together), as shown here: (1)[all data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxV7K.png) (2)[zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojkmw.png)

I've tried reducing the data volume from 5000 to 2500 images, while it didn't improve at all.

Does anyone know the reason and how to solve this? Thank you.